# Simple ASP form validation - swapped?

Tags: forms, validation, asp-classic, ado

I am trying to do some very simple form validation checking for null or '' (empty) using a conditional, but when I submit my form with ALL BLANK FIELDS, it does the latter section of my code.

And when I fill out all of my fields it does that other part. So when they are blank, tell the user, which is the first section of the conditional, I have pasted my code below. Any suggestions on what I can do? Is it my "OR" or "AND"

```
if(((f_name <> null) or (f_name <> "")) or ((l_name <> null) or (l_name <> "")) or ((username <> null) or (username <> "")) or ((password <> null) or (password <> ""))) then
    'response.redirect("account_created.asp")
    response.write("You have not filled in all fields.")
else
    Set objConn = ConnectDB()
    query       = "INSERT INTO [user] (username,[password],f_name,l_name) VALUES ('"& username &"','"& password &"','"& f_name &"','"& l_name &"')"
    Set objs    = objConn.Execute(query)
    response.write(query)
    'Response.Redirect ("thankyou.asp")

end if
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. you do not need all the parentheses
2. if fname et al are the textboxes, you need fname.Text instead

Comment: classic asp, not asp.net...no .Text properties

Answer (score 0):

In general it should be sufficient to check for empty string (such as f_name <> "").  I however usually do this with a trim and len. len(trim(f_name)) > 0.  It takes care of all spaces.  You should reconsider your parenthesis since they are not necessary.
if len(trim(f_name)) > 0 or ... then